# Evaluating $\int_{1}^{e}(2x-1/x)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I need help evaluating the following integral:

> $$\int_{1}^{e}\left(2x-\dfrac1x \right)dx$$

Comment: use dollars signs to enclose mathematical formulae.

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

$$\int 2x\,dx=x^2$$

$$\int\frac{dx}{x}=\log x\ldots$$

Comment: + a constant...

Comment: Hehe...like the joke with the waitress. +1

Comment: Yes. Thats what came to my mind.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Recall that $$\int x^n dx = \dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n+1} + \text{constant}$$ where $n \in \mathbb{R} \backslash \{-1\}$. For $n=-1$, we have $$\int \dfrac{dx}x = \log(x) + \text{constant}$$